# Shouldn't array indexing time complexity be O(1)

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

Today I was trying to understand differences between array, IEnumerable, ICollection and IList and decided to test them myself, upon doing so I wrote this code for array initially and it felt weird.
What am i doing wrong here?

```
public long[] nums
{
    get {
        long l = 200000000;
        long[] arr = new long[l];
        for (long i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            arr[i] = i;
        }
        var x = l - 1;
        long val = 0;
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        val = arr[0];
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds); // 0
        stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        val = arr[l-1];
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds); // 199999999
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Comment: accessing, pushing or popping a value in an array is O(1). Linearly searching through an array via its index is O(n).

Comment: Is the second comment accurate? It took `199999999` milliseconds? Thats more than 55 hours...

Comment: `199999999` is the contents of `arr[l-1]`, *not* the result from `stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds()`. There's your mistake.

Comment: You are trying to measure the width of a hair with a wooden imperial units ruler. (Figuratively speaking) Or maybe better: You are trying to measure the duration of the blink of an eye with a manual stopwatch. <- Would you consider any of these valid measurements?

Answer (score 3):

You should consider the time scales here.

An array access should be compiled to a few instructions. The clock speed of most computers are 2-5GHz, or 0.5-0.2ns. One instruction might take anywhere from a few clock cycles, to a few hundred, depending on data availability and many other factors. Measuring times at the instruction level is complicated since the CPU will try to do as much work as possible in parallel.

You are measuring times in *milliseconds* that is close to a million times longer than the times we are talking about. Stopwatch uses the "High Precision Event Timer", and this is typically running at 100Mhz, or 100ns, so even if you printed ticks your result would at best tell you if the data was in the cache or not.

In conclusion, array access is considered "constant time", and your way of measuring is not correct for these time scales. Consider using Benchmark.net if you want to get accurate numbers.

Note that in reality, the time to load some memory can actually vary widely depending on *where* the memory is. If it is in the L1 cache the access will take a few nanoseconds, if in main memory it will take on the order of hundreds of nanoseconds, if it is swapped to disk it might take *whole seconds*.

Answer (score 2):

Array indexing in most programming languages, including C#, which you seem to be using, typically has a time complexity of O(1). This means that accessing an element at a specific index in an array should take a constant amount of time regardless of the size of the array.

In your code, when you access arr[0] and arr[l-1], you are indeed performing constant-time array indexing. Your usage of the Stopwatch to measure the time it takes to perform these operations may not be accurate in measuring the actual time complexity because it can be influenced by various factors such as the current state of the system, other processes running concurrently, and how the JIT (Just-In-Time) compiler optimizes your code.

In practice, you may observe very small variations in the measured time for accessing elements at different indices, but the time complexity remains O(1).

The code you provided should work as expected for testing array indexing, but keep in mind that the elapsed time measurements might not always be precise down to the nanosecond level due to factors outside your control.